# Android - Drawing lines using bitmap on TouchImageView

Tags: android, bitmap

Basically I would like to draw lines on an image so that when that image is zoomed, the lines would also get zoomed proportionally, or any kind of interactivity like fling or zoom reset. I'm using TouchImageView as my ImageView and here's my code

```
public class ParkA extends Activity{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.parka);
        TouchImageView parka = (TouchImageView) findViewById(R.id.parka);
        parka.setImageResource(R.drawable.parka);

        Bitmap lineABmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(480, 640, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas lineACanvas = new Canvas(lineABmp);
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(10);
        lineACanvas.drawBitmap(lineABmp,0 ,0, null);
        //lineACanvas.drawLine(60, 64, 60, 500, paint);

        TouchImageView linea = new TouchImageView(this);
        linea = (TouchImageView) findViewById(R.id.parka);
        linea.setImageBitmap(lineABmp);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();


    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {


        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {


    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        //Do Nothing
    }

}
```

Here's my xml file

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.kmparkit.ParkA" >

    <com.km.parkit.TouchImageView
        android:id="@+id/parka"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:contentDescription="@string/imageDesc"
        android:scaleType="matrix"  />
        <!-- android:src="@drawable/parka" --> 

</RelativeLayout>
```

If I change the `Bitmap.createBitmap(480, 640, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);`

Into `Bitmap.createBitmap(parka.getWidth(), parka.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);`

The logcat says that width and height must be > 0

If I drawLine, only the green line itself would be shown

What am I missing here in order to create a TouhImageView picture with lines drawn on it?

UPDATE :

Here's the solution!

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.parka);

        TouchImageView parka = (TouchImageView) findViewById(R.id.parka);
        parka.setImageResource(R.drawable.parka);

        Bitmap lineABmp = ((BitmapDrawable)parka.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
        Bitmap lineAMutBmp = lineABmp.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);

        Canvas lineACanvas = new Canvas(lineAMutBmp);
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(10);
        lineACanvas.drawLine(82, 1058, 82, 858, paint);

        parka.setImageBitmap(lineAMutBmp);
    }
```

I have to copy the bitmap in order to make it mutable and use `parka.setImageResource();` and `parka.setImageBitmap()` to display the picture and the lines in one `TouchImageView` while drawing the lines using `Canvas`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

**EDIT** : this should do the trick ;)

```
    setContentView(R.layout.parka);
    TouchImageView parka = (TouchImageView) findViewById(R.id.parka);
    parka.setImageResource(R.drawable.parka);
    Bitmap lineABmp = ((BitmapDrawable)parka.getDrawable()).getBitmap();

    Bitmap copy = Bitmap.createBitmap(lineABmp);

    Canvas lineACanvas = new Canvas(copy);
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
    paint.setStrokeWidth(10);
    lineACanvas.drawLine(60, 64, 60, 500, paint);

    parka.setImageBitmap(copy);
```

Happy coding :D

Comment: It was still the same until I made changes into the Bitmap part to this `Bitmap lineABmp = ((BitmapDrawable)parka.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
     Bitmap lineAMutBmp = lineABmp.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);` Now it works! But only to show the image from `setImageResource` but nothing on the canvas :(

Comment: Maybe the bitmap is very small. Try with lineACanvas.drawLine(0, 0,lineACanvas.getWidth() , ineACanvas.getHeight(), paint);

Comment: @Gordak You're setting `lineABmp` as `TouchImageView`s bitmap when you should be using `copy`. You used `copy ` to create your canvas so it is the Bitmap that will be drawn to.

Comment: Wooott! It worked!!! Hahahahahhahaha!! Thanks!! Another question though, how to know the total length of the drawable? Does the number in width and height means the pixel as in x * y? I need to draw precise lines :D

Comment: Use the methods getWidth() and getHeight of Canvas to get width and height, in pixels.

Comment: I was thinking about doing manual work as in getting the image resolution, because I failed at using the `getWidth()` and `getHeight()` before you told me, but silly me, I've written `parka.getWidth()`, it is supposed to be `lineACanvas.getWidth()`! I used Toast for the information retrieval. Thanks for the help :D

Comment: A quick piece of advice. Instead of using Toast, use Log.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html

Comment: Ohh thanks! I used it for the database creation check and I forgot all about it by the time I got to the parking lot drawing ._. Thanks for all your help, much appreciated in helping me to understand Android coding :D